# Is "his" ambiguious in this sentence about Russell Wallace and Darwin?

Tags: ambiguity, personal-pronouns

> When Russell Wallace and Darwin independently proposed similar theories, Darwin had already accumulated extensive evidence with which to support **his** ideas.

I found that on 'Majortest.com'. Here it is said that using **his** is wrong as it is an ambiguous pronoun. By using "his" it is unclear if the evidence supports Darwin, Wallace, or both?

To correct this should I use **his own** or something else?

Comment: That's a ridiculous question on majortest.  Why would Darwin be accumulating evidence to support a theory of which he was unaware?  They proposed their theories *independently*.

Comment: "Although Jones and Smith reached the finish-line in a dead heat, Jones had dropped his baton."  It's a mystery how Jones ever managed to get hold of Smith's baton!

Answer (score 2):

A reason *his* could be wrong is because it's possibly ambiguous, we don't technically really know if *his* is referring to Darwin or Wallace, though I think it would be safe to assume it's referring back to Darwin.

Since the ideas are the same between Darwin and Wallace, it's safest to not use a possessive determiner, but a demonstrative one instead, e.g. *those ideas*.

Additional context may make it more sense to say "his own", e.g. if the focus of the preceding sentences is on Darwin, for example.

Comment: The antecedent is Darwin, ergo his would refer to Darwin. his own is just emphatic. The question was not about the possibility of its being wrong...